# JSON Directory index with PHP - file access?

Tags: php, json, file-access

This is a very simple version without any error handling of what i want my php-script to do:

```
echo json_encode( scandir($_GET['d']) );
```

Now i want to restrict file access for this, such that the index is only built, if the given path is one, which say Apache also serves an auto-index for.

Alternatively, if this cannot be achieved easily, it would be sufficient to check, whether the queried directory is owned by the same user php running php (i.e. `posix_geteuid();`)

Comment: I don't know about the apache version, but have you tried `fileowner($_GET['d']) == posix_geteuid()`?

Comment: Yes, sadly that does not really work because fileowner fails and generates warnings in many cases, however I'm not able to say exactly why.

Comment: It can fail if php process owner does not have permissions to read that directory. You should probably extend the condition to: `is_readable($_GET['d']) && fileowner($_GET['d']) == posix_geteuid()`